# ffmpeg not working with php exec. Error: 133

Tags: php, ffmpeg, exec

I am trying to generate thumbnails from video files using ffmpeg.

When I run the following command from my Mac terminal it works fine:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -ss 00:00:01.000 -vframes 1 out.png
```

When I try to use the same command from php exec it doesn't work:

```
exec('/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -ss 00:00:01.000 -vframes 1 test.png 2>&1', $output, $return_var);
```

$output:

```
Array
(
   [0] => dyld: Symbol not found: _sqlite3_intarray_bind
   [1] =>   Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/Versions/A/CoreData
   [2] =>   Expected in: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
   [3] =>  in /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/Versions/A/CoreData
)
```

$return_var:

```
133
```

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be because `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` is linked to XAMPP libraries folder. Put the below line before `exec` command and it should work:

```
putenv('DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH');
```